# How to get site settings in a django project converted to wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I have  a django site onto which I have added wagtail following these [instructions](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html).

I have set up Social Media setting using these [instructions](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7.1/reference/contrib/settings.html)

I have sucessfully added details on the admin page ad I can return and edit these details

However I cannot access them in a template

If I display

```
{{settings.site_settings.SiteSettings.facebook}}
```

I get '' (tested using {% if settings.site_settings.SiteSettings.facebook == '' ...)

However

```
{{settings.site_settings.SiteSettings}}
```

returns None

and

```
{{settings.site_settings}}
```

returns SettingsModuleProxy(site_settings)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that I had misspelt the *SiteSettings* class name in models.py (very red-face)